# Arrays in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Ok, I have a decent understanding on whats going on here. I enter 6 char characters and it suppose to equal to $0x3a which is 58. So the array goes through each character and does a & with $0xf which is 15. Then what I don't get is what its doing on line 39. For example if I enter b and then do & 0xf on it, it becomes 2, after the 39 line, %ecx become 6 and I don't know how that calculation is done. What I thought line 39 is, x + 4y, so %rsi + (%rdx * 4). Does anybody know what happens on line 39 exactly?

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
0x000055555555547d <+0>:     push   %rbx
0x000055555555547e <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
0x0000555555555481 <+4>:     callq  0x5555555556fe <string_length>
0x0000555555555486 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax
0x0000555555555489 <+12>:    jne    0x5555555554bc <phase_5+63>
0x000055555555548b <+14>:    mov    %rbx,%rax
0x000055555555548e <+17>:    lea    0x6(%rbx),%rdi
0x0000555555555492 <+21>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
0x0000555555555497 <+26>:    lea    0x1622(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556ac0 <array.3416>
0x000055555555549e <+33>:    movzbl (%rax),%edx
0x00005555555554a1 <+36>:    and    $0xf,%edx
0x00005555555554a4 <+39>:    add    (%rsi,%rdx,4),%ecx
0x00005555555554a7 <+42>:    add    $0x1,%rax
0x00005555555554ab <+46>:    cmp    %rdi,%rax
0x00005555555554ae <+49>:    jne    0x55555555549e <phase_5+33>
0x00005555555554b0 <+51>:    cmp    $0x3a,%ecx
0x00005555555554b3 <+54>:    je     0x5555555554ba <phase_5+61>
0x00005555555554b5 <+56>:    callq  0x555555555a14 <explode_bomb>
0x00005555555554ba <+61>:    pop    %rbx
0x00005555555554bb <+62>:    retq
0x00005555555554bc <+63>:    callq  0x555555555a14 <explode_bomb>
0x00005555555554c1 <+68>:    jmp    0x55555555548b <phase_5+14>
```

Comment: `add    (%rsi,%rdx,4),%ecx` in AT&T syntax means `add ecx, [rsi+rdx*4]` in Intel syntax. This directly translates into C-like syntax `ecx += *(rsi+rdx*4);`. Does this let you understand it better?

Comment: It still doesn't add up to my calculations. When i enter bceijl as my string, I get 55 only when i feel like the number should be way bigger?. I need 58

Comment: Yeah I am using gdb as we speak

Comment: Just stop at +39 and examine each of `$ecx`, `$rsi` and `$rdx`, as well as what is there in `*(int*)($rsi+$rdx*4)`.

Comment: I tried that. For example for my first char which is b. The oxff of that is 2. I assuming it stores it in %ecx. %rsi is 2 and %rdx is 2 since b is 2. So its (2,2,4) and when i check the ecx, its comes out to 6.

Comment: I dont know how to comes out to 6, unless im doing something wrong on my end

Comment: I think you forgot that `rsi` points to `array.3416`, and you seem to not have examined its contents.

Comment: I examine it with x/d and it always come out to 2

Comment: You'd better show what exactly you do and what exactly doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: idk, For example, I enter abcdjp. It goes through the array and that line 39 calculates all of my chars. The total is 45. I have no idea how it calculates that

Comment: Show your whole debugging session. Otherwise, without [mcve] no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: The array 'array.3416' contains 16 4-byte-values. Which values are those? Your entered letters (the right hex digit of them) are used as indices in that array.

Comment: Since im new to assembly, you mean it has 16 indexes? and how would i find those values using gdb? @Sebastian

Comment: I have been here for hours, cant figure out the 6 char string that i need to pass this phase

Comment: I got it! finally! I know understand. I had to do x/16 to view my array. It was searching in the array, it wasnt adding anything up. The add statement was confusing me

Comment: To be more correct, it has one index (one-dimensional array) with 16 possible index values: 0 .. 15. The 'and operation' takes the rightmost hex digit of the entered character (ASCII code: @=0, A=1, B=2, ..., O=15, P=0, Q=1, ...). Then it fetches the corresponding value from the array and adds up all 6 array values, one for each of the password letters.

Comment: @Sebastian Thats correct! Thank you !

Comment: @Bobby.lock I put it into an answer so that you can accept the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array 'array.3416' contains 16 4-byte-values.
Your entered letters (the right hex digit of them) are used as index in that array.

The index can have 16 possible index values: 0 .. 15.
The and operation in line 36 takes the rightmost hex digit of the entered character (ASCII code & 0xF: '@'=>0, 'A'=>1, 'B'=>2, ..., 'O'=>15, 'P'=>0, 'Q'=>1, ...).

Then it fetches the corresponding value from the array and adds up at the same time (in line 39) all 6 array values, one for each of the password letters by looping.